# Print composer changing orientation when saved to a template

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I am having an issue while creating a template. When I save my Print composer to a template for my peers to use, the orientation is not saved. I have changed the orientation from landscape to portrait, and then save the template and close it. when I reopen the template, the orientation automatically changes back to portrait. If I then change it back to portrait, my text boxes surrounding my map data frame are redistributed. I added a formula @layout_pagewidth = 210 and @layout_pageheight = 297 in an attempt to make the orientation permanent with no resolve.

Comment: Which QGIS version and for which platform are you using? I can confirm that this works fine for QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon on Windows 7 64-bit (both laptop and pc which I used to transfer the template file).

Comment: I am using the same QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon on Windows 7 64-bit. I save the template with the orientation set to portrait but when it is saved, closed, and re opened it has changed back to landscape. I can just hit the resize button and it fixes the issue, but when I share the template with peers that are not using Lyon, they don't have the same luxury.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a WAD (work as designed). Before loading the template in the print composer, set the orientation manually to the correct orientation of the template. I usually add the orientation to the name of the template like A4_portrait or A4_landscape.

Comment: sorry, new to all of this